# Parse Nested array string to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a sample nested array string as below:

```
const content = `[
  {
    type: 'paragraph',
    content: 'How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?',
  },
  {
    type: 'paragraph',
    content: 'How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?',
  },
  {
    type: 'image',
    src: 'http://upload.sample.com/2016/0407/1460024231806.jpg',
    meta: {
      alt: 'Parse String to Float or Int',
      title: 'Parse String to Float or Int',
      caption: 'Parse String to Float or Int',
    },
  }
]`;
```

As it is a string, I use the `JSON.parse()` method to parse it to an array, but it throws this error:

`VM926:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 10`

Is there some way to parse this string array to an array?

Comment: Well, that’s not JSON, so you can’t use `JSON.parse` here. Every property name and every string needs to have double quotes around itself `"`. Also, remove the trailing commas.

Comment: First create a valid JSON. Look at this link if you don't know about JSON : https://www.json.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stringified JSON usually has double quotes for all the keys.
Also extra commas(,s) should be discarded for it to be a valid json.

```
const content = `[
  {
    "type": "paragraph",
    "content": "How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?"
  },
  {
    "type": "paragraph",
    "content": "How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?"
  },
  {
    "type": "image",
    "src": "http://upload.sample.com/2016/0407/1460024231806.jpg",
    "meta": {
      "alt": "Parse String to Float or Int",
      "title": "Parse String to Float or Int",
      "caption": "Parse String to Float or Int"
    }
  }
]`;
```